# Change the background colour of a div when a certain div is showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three divs for a Twitter post, a Facebook post and a LinkedIn post and these make up a carousel.

These are then inside of another div called #social-media-feeds.

I am wondering if it is possible to change the background colour of #social-media-feeds based on which div in the carousel is showing.

So when the twitter div shows I would like the background colour of #social-media-feeds to be #00aced, when the facebook div shows I would like the background colour to be #3b5998, and when the linkedin div shows I would like the background colour to be #007bb5.

If this is possible I'd really appreciate a hand. Thanks!

Comment: show us your code please. for example here :
https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: We are programmers here, we can read code. It's definitely possible, probably by using your carousel's callback, but you still need to show us some code.

Comment: give your carousel code snippet please.

Answer (score 0):

This is terribly formed code, but it works. I can't pretend to know what your code looks like so I hope this helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            #social-media-feeds {
                display: inline-block;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .post {
                display: none;
            }
            #leftButton {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 0%;
                height: 30px;
                width: 60px;
                text-align: right;
                background-color: gray;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            #rightButton {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                right: 0%;
                height: 30px;
                width: 60px;
                background-color: gray;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="leftButton"><</div>
        <div id="rightButton">></div>
        <div id="social-media-feeds">
            <div id="facebook" class="post">Facebook</div>
            <div id="twitter" class="post">Twitter</div>
            <div id="linkedIn" class="post">LinkedIn</div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var socialMediaFeedsDiv = document.getElementById('social-media-feeds');
            var backgroundColors = ["#3b5998", "#00aced", "#007bb5"];
            var posts = document.getElementsByClassName('post');
            var index = 0;
            posts[index].style.display = 'inline-block';
            socialMediaFeedsDiv.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColors[index];    
            var leftButton = document.getElementById('leftButton');
            leftButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                posts[index].style.display = 'none';
                index--;
                if (index < 0) {
                    index = posts.length - 1;
                }
                posts[index].style.display = 'inline-block';
                socialMediaFeedsDiv.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColors[index];
            });
            var rightButton = document.getElementById('rightButton');
            rightButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                posts[index].style.display = 'none';
                index++;
                if (index > (posts.length - 1)) {
                    index = 0;
                }
                posts[index].style.display = 'inline-block';
                socialMediaFeedsDiv.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColors[index];
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```